# condense results into 1 result under a certain limit

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I have a result set that has a percentage of the total in 1 column and a name in the other column.

So for example -

```
 Name | Percentage
 Jill | 12
 Sam  | 24
 Steve| 2
Jeff  | 3
Elvis | 59
```

I am trying to condense any result thats less than 15% into on row,

so my result would be

```
         Name | Percentage
 Everyone else| 17
         Sam  | 24
        Elvis | 59
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT tt.Name, SUM([Percentage]) AS [Percentage]
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (CASE WHEN [Percentage] < 15 
                    THEN 'Everyone else' 
                    ELSE Name 
               END) 
     ) tt(Name)
GROUP BY tt.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` *expression* in a *derived table* (the sub-query) to put all less than 15% people together. `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select name, sum(Percentage)
from
(
    select case when Percentage > 15 then name
                else 'Everyone else'
           end as name,
           Percentage
    from tablename
) dt
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple condition, you can just use `CASE` expressions:

```
select (case when percentage < 15 then 'Everyone else'
             else name
        end) as name,
       sum(percentage) as percentage
from t
group by (case when percentage < 15 then 'Everyone else'
               else name
          end)
order by sum(percentage) asc;
```